# How to convert from string to XElement object

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a string like this: `"<Root><Child>Hey</Child></Root>"`

How can I convert this to an `XElement` Object?

Comment: What do you want the resulting XML to be?

Comment: @George: `XElement`, that part of the question was clear...

Comment: Would `Hey` be the tag name or value? If value, what should the name be?

Comment: Looks like the question is edited to be clear now.

Comment: realn, note that you must **code-format** xml (using back ticks `` or a four-space indent) in order for it to appear correctly in your question. See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 94):

Use [XElement.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714.aspx) method like below

```
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("<Root><Child>Hey</Child></Root>");
Console.WriteLine(xmlTree);
```

Comment: +1 :-) (I've change the sample XML to his sample XML. The "meat" of the code doesn't change)