# Unable to convert string to XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xdoc

I am creating a xml file, but am unable to convert the string in the tag `<Nb>`

```
 <Header>
 <Body>
 <Nb>13</Nb>    
 </Body>
 </Header>
```

How do I convert it to an XElement item? I want to avoid using Linq, XmlDoc if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the XElement.Parse like so

```
private XElement XmlNumber()
{    
   XElement nb = XElement.Parse("<Header><Body><Nb>13</Nb></Body></Header>");

   return nb;    
}
```

Examples here: [How to convert from string to XElement object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847424/how-to-convert-from-string-to-xelement-object)

Comment: Why do you have two "<" at beginning of xml?